# Git folder and github repository connection issue

Tags: git, github, repository

I had a git folder in my computer which is linked with github repository. Whenever, I do some work in that folder, I pushed it in my github repository. Now, accidently I deleted my git folder. How can I push my work on github repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you would need to first pull github repository to your local computer and then you could continue as usual. There might additional step involved depending on your project, if you have some dependencies that are not synced with github, you would need to install them.

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo-name
```

this command will create folder repo-name and copy your saved repo from github to your local computer.

Comment: After using git clone command, can I do commit and push my work to the GitHub repo? If yes, then how?

Comment: if you want to work on that repo better option is fork.